# Imitate a product using cms static block

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

My website trades raw materials & chemicals. I will have many suppliers listing their products on my website. Many of these suppliers will offer identically named products, with only the product attributes differentiating them.

My questions: 
How can I imitate a product using cms static blocks?
How can I assign bulk static blocks to certain categories?
Ensure these static blocks contain a hyperlink which redirect to product category.

For example:
A well known chemical compound, such as "Sodium Chloride" may have 10 separate listings from different suppliers. These identical products will be assigned to its own category.
Here is the category url for sodium chloride: http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/products/full-product-list/s-products/sodium-chloride.html

If you viewed the above url, you will see that any "sodium chloride" listings have been assigned to the "sodium chloride" category.

Why do I want to do this?

Once I start listing thousands of products, I don't want every single product to be displayed within categories such as: http://www.efficienttrade.co.nz/products.html

Obviously, a customer will be browsing for a specific chemical compound and therefore, displaying all products (many of which will be identical), will become very cluttered.

So instead, I want to display a static block for each unique product, which will represent all identical products with that name. User should then be able to click on the block which will redirect user to the actual product category. These static blocks will be displayed within specific categories.

In summary, I need an easy method to create these blocks programmatically. I don't want to be creating 3000 individual cms blocks.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles and signatures in posts

Answer (score 1):

You could creating configurable products and set an attribute called supplier.
It would be very much like configuring clothes by color (size, style attribute) and there a lot of examples out there about how to do that.

The good thing is that the configurable product can be set to be visible/invisible in the category browsing and search, so it would be your choice where you want to display it.

Also, for each attribute you can use a different image (maybe with the supplier logo?) and have different prices.

Here is a screen cast on how to create configurable products:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/media/screencasts/configurable-products/view

Comment: This does not answer my problem sorry. You indicate that I want to display my supplier products, but infact I want to create product blocks which do not refer to an actual product, but are used to simply redirect user to product category.

Answer (score 0):

In your static/CMS block write something like `{{block type="core/template" template="path_to/your_template.phtml" product_id="37"}}`

In your_template.phtml you could do something like:

```
<?php
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
if(!$_product->getId()) {
    return; // Failed to load product
}
?>
<h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()); ?></h2>
<p>Do more awesome stuff here</p>
```

Similarly you could load product collections by categories, arbitrary attributes and such.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am trying it out now. Will let you know my results :)